# Accessing a VB6 Control using a variable

Tags: vb6

I have a set of controls say Shape1, Shape2, Shape3 (**not a control array**). Can I access a control using Shapei or Shape(i), in a loop or something, where i is the variable. Or is there any method to do the same. Please give me a solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Making your controls a control array is the way to do this.

Comment: Thanks Mark , but in my case a control array is not applicable. I hope you don't know what's my case. Please try to give an answer that sticks to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think Peter has the right idea using an array to build the control loop.

I think you can just use a loop to access control name directly

```
Sub DoShapeStuff(intNumShapes as integer)
   Dim shp As Control

   For i = 1 to intNumShapes 
      Set shp = me.Controls("Shape" & i)
      ' Do Shape manipulation stuff here using shp variable
   Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Turning the controls you need to iterate over into a control array is the easy way to do this, and usually just makes everything make more sense.

If you really have to do this the hard way, though, I think the approach would be to use the Form's [Controls property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa234180%28v=vs.60%29) to get its [Controls collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa445317%28v%3Dvs.60%29). You can iterate over all the controls, find the one you're looking for by its name, and then take the action you need to on it.

Something like this, though this is from memory as I haven't programmed in VB6 for many many years and don't have the IDE installed, so I may have some detail of syntax wrong:

```
Private Function GetShapeByName(ByVal ShapeName as String) As Shape
    Dim currentControl as Control
    For Each currentControl In Controls
        If currentControl.Name = ShapeName Then
            Set GetShapeByName = currentControl
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

And then where you want to loop through each Shape, you can do something like:

```
Dim i as Integer
Dim CurrentShape as Shape
For i = 1 To 3
    Set CurrentShape = GetShapeByName("Shape" & i)
    ' Do something with CurrentShape here
Next
```

But as you can see, that's a lot of work for each lookup you need to do, and just emulating a control array badly.